# Is the likelihood a function of random variables ($X_i$) or a function of realisations of random variables ($x_i$)?

Tags: statistics

Is the likelihood a function of random variables ($X_i$) or a function of realisations of random variables ($x_i$) ?

Is there a consensus on this in the statistics community ?

Comment: Please complete your question.

Comment: @Kamal Saleh : it seems to me that my question is perfectly defined. I have now added explicitely $X_i$ and $x_i$ to help the reader.

Comment: I understand it now I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A likelihood is a function of the *parameters* for a fixed realization of a sample.  For instance, a sample $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m)$ drawn from binomial distributions with common parameter $p$ but possibly different (but fixed and known) $n_i$ will have likelihood for $p$ proportional to
$$\mathcal L(p \mid x_1, \ldots, x_m) \propto \prod_{i=1}^m p^{x_i} (1-p)^{n_i - x_i} = p^{\sum x_i} (1-p)^{\sum (n_i - x_i)},$$ and this is regarded as a function of the parameter $p$.  That is not to say that $n_i$ and $x_i$ must take on specific values, but rather, the emphasis is on how $\mathcal L$ varies with $p$.

Comment: Isn't it incompatible with the following ? (a) the Fisher information is a variance of a function of the likelihood (or an expected value of a function of the derivative of the likelihood). (b) the variance is defined for a random variable (not for a realisation of a random variable). Then, how the fact that (A) the likelihood is a function of *realization* of random variables* be compatible with the fact that (B) a function of the likelihood (Fisher information) is a variance, so a function of *random variables* ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian As I clearly stated, the likelihood is a function of the **parameter(s)**.  The Fisher information is the variance of the score.  These are not contradictory statements.  The score is the gradient (derivative) of the log-likelihood with respect to the **parameter(s).**

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.